# How to have body-parser parse data into a schema of arrays?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman, body-parser

could you please help me out with this one?

My mongoose schema is looking like this

```
var TheSchema   = new Schema({
    name: 'String',
    givenTask: [{
    today: 'String',
    tomorrow: 'String'
    }]
});
```

How can i make body-parser parse this data into MongoDB? I've been trying this:

```
.post(function(req, res) {

        var schema = new TheSchema();

        schema.name = req.body.name;
        schema.givenTask.today = req.body.today;
        schema.givenTask.tomorrow = req.body.tomorrow;

        schema.save(function(err) {
        });

    });
```

Is there anything I should look out for in Postman? I thought I would just name the body fields like: 
name:
now:
later:

Could you please correct me? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: First, your names have to match the names you create in the schema, so `now` and `later` do not exist in the schema you demo'd.  Second, what is the actual problem?  Are the properties not in the body? Or are you getting some different problem?

Comment: Thank you, I have edited this. It was problem only in this version here. The problem is that I cannot get the data in MongoDB like this, it wouldn't recognise the field today and tomorrow, and it wouldn't build up the array. It just keeps the schema array empty. These are going to be entered from the body, yes.

Comment: Ahh it's because you are calling givenTask an array `[]`.  You will need to initialize the array as empty, then push the objects into it.  Something like `schema.givenTask = []; schema.givenTask.push({today: req.body.today, tomorrow: req.body.tomorrow});`

Comment: AAAAHHH! It's working! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert into the `givenTask` array, you'll need to initialize it and then push objects into it.

```
var schema = new TheSchema();

schema.name = req.body.name;
schema.givenTask = [];
schema.givenTask.push({today: req.body.today, tomorrow: req.body.tomorrow});

schema.save(function(err) {
});
```